# Access to all languages in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, localization, ios-simulator

I am trying to test various `localizations` in the `iOS 7 simulator`.

The problem is that, I see very few `languages`. I see all the `languages` in the `iOS 6` simulator, but `iOS 7` has very few choices. What do I need to do to get all the `languages` I have in `iOS 6`?

Comment: How many is "very few"?  I see 30+ choices in my simulator.

Comment: Odd.. Which 8 languages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing languages on iOS simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092372/missing-languages-on-ios-simulator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

That's strange. I'm unsure exactly what needs to be installed but check Xcode's preferences and see under the `Downloads` tab you have the following:

[image: Downloads Tab contents]

I'm guessing whatever you need is in either the documentation or components.

**Option 2:**

Ensure you are using the latest Xcode (that is Xcode 5.1.1)

It could be you are using a BETA version of Xcode 5 which may not have came with all languages

[image]

**Option 3:**

If you installed simulator 7.1 before 7.0, you might need to install 7.0 still, as suggested by this:

[Missing languages on iOS simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092372/missing-languages-on-ios-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

I do know that this does not solve the problem of having only few languages in the simulator. But it seems like that you just want to test an App in various languages.

You can run an App on a device (and probably also on simulator) with a specific language by adding

```
-AppleLanguages "(English)"
```

to the run arguments in Xcode. (Replace `English` with the respective language.)

Just add that to the `Arguments Passed On Launch` which can be found at `Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme... > Run <App>.app > Arguments`.